Transform a JSON array by Jolt into a new JSON object
I have an array of JSON Objects that I need to transform into a new array of JSON Objects that align with my schema. I am new to Jolt and my output is not what I need.
I tried multiple ways but not able to get my desired result.
This is my Input JSON: It has 2 exactly same entries of Joe Hashashi  in product Yearly and Leo Biz in product Monthly.
{
  "totalApplication": {
    "applicationName": "MSOffice",
    "source": "EMAIL",
    "products": [
      {
        "productName": "Yearly",
        "userList": [
          {
            "userId": "3544353",
            "email": "joeh@yahoo.com",
            "userName": "Joe Hashashi",
            "lastActive": "1705088660"
          },
          {
            "userId": "3544353",
            "email": "joeh@yahoo.com",
            "userName": "Joe Hashashi",
            "lastActive": "1705088660"
          },
          {
            "userId": "3544354",
            "email": "jacob@yahoo.com",
            "userName": "Jacob Martin",
            "lastActive": "1705088661"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "productName": "Monthly",
        "userList": [
          {
            "userId": "4545455",
            "email": "amandak@yahoo.com",
            "userName": "Amanda Kore",
            "lastActive": "1705088662"
          },
          {
            "userId": "4545456",
            "email": "leo@yahoo.com",
            "userName": "Leo Biz",
            "lastActive": "1705088663"
          },
          {
            "userId": "4545456",
            "email": "leo@yahoo.com",
            "userName": "Leo Biz",
            "lastActive": "1705088663"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

This is the Jolt Spec I tried:
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "totalApplication": {
        "products": {
          "*": {
            "userList": {
              "*": {
                "productUserId": "=concat(@(3,planName),'-',@(1,userId),'-',@(1,email),'-',@(1,userName),'-',@(1,lastActive))"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "totalApplication": {
        "products": {
          "*": {
            "userList": {
              "*": {
                "userName": "@(1,productUserId).name",
                "email": "@(1,productUserId).email",
                "userId": "@(1,productUserId).userId",
                "productUserId": "@(1,productUserId).productUserId",
                "lastActive": "@(1,productUserId).additionalAttribute.lastActive",
                "@(2,productName)": "@(1,productUserId).additionalAttribute.productName",
                "@(4,applicationName)": "@(1,productUserId).additionalAttribute.applicationName"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": "[&1].name",
        "email": "[&1].email",
        "userId": "[&1].userId",
        "additionalAttribute": "[&1].additionalAttribute",
        "productUserId": null
      }
    }
  }
]

With above mentioned specs I am getting below result. My jolt spec adding the user details in the same object if 2 user objects have exactly same details. I want separate details even though if 2 user objects in the userList have same details. You can see the user with name Joe Hashashi  and Leo Biz has 2 entries in the userList in my input json and after jolt transformation both details coming under same object in the response.
[ 
 {
   "name" : [ "Joe Hashashi", "Joe Hashashi" ],
   "email" : [ "joeh@yahoo.com", "joeh@yahoo.com" ],
   "userId" : [ "3544353", "3544353" ],
   "additionalAttribute" : {
     "productName" : [ "Yearly", "Yearly" ],
     "applicationName" : [ "MSOffice", "MSOffice" ],
     "lastActive" : [ "1705088660", "1705088660" ]
  }
 }, 
 {
   "name" : "Jacob Martin",
   "email" : "jacob@yahoo.com",
   "userId" : "3544354",
   "additionalAttribute" : {
     "productName" : "Yearly",
     "applicationName" : "MSOffice",
     "lastActive" : "1705088661"
  }
 }, 
 {
   "name" : "Amanda Kore",
   "email" : "amandak@yahoo.com",
   "userId" : "4545455",
   "additionalAttribute" : {
     "productName" : "Monthly",
     "applicationName" : "MSOffice",
     "lastActive" : "1705088662"
  }
 }, 
 {
   "name" : [ "Leo Biz", "Leo Biz" ],
   "email" : [ "leo@yahoo.com", "leo@yahoo.com" ],
   "userId" : [ "4545456", "4545456" ],
   "additionalAttribute" : {
     "productName" : [ "Monthly", "Monthly" ],
     "applicationName" : [ "MSOffice", "MSOffice" ],
     "lastActive" : [ "1705088663", "1705088663" ]
  }
 } 
]

I want separate details even if more than 2 user objects in the userList have exactly same details. Below is the desired output I want. You can see the user with name Joe Hashashi  has comes in separate objects.
[
  {
    "additionalAttribute": {
      "productName": "Yearly",
      "applicationName": "MSOffice",
      "lastActive": "1705088660"
    },
    "userId": "3544353",
    "email": "joeh@yahoo.com",
    "name": "Joe Hashashi"
  },
  {
    "additionalAttribute": {
      "productName": "Yearly",
      "applicationName": "MSOffice",
      "lastActive": "1705088660"
    },
    "userId": "3544353",
    "email": "joeh@yahoo.com",
    "name": "Joe Hashashi"
  },
  {
    "additionalAttribute": {
      "productName": "Monthly",
      "applicationName": "MSOffice",
      "lastActive": "1705088662"
    },
    "userId": "4545455",
    "email": "amandak@yahoo.com",
    "name": "Amanda Kore"
  },
  {
    "additionalAttribute": {
      "productName": "Monthly",
      "applicationName": "MSOffice",
      "lastActive": "1705088663"
    },
    "userId": "4545456",
    "email": "leo@yahoo.com",
    "name": "Leo Biz"
  },
  {
    "additionalAttribute": {
      "productName": "Yearly",
      "applicationName": "MSOffice",
      "lastActive": "1705088661"
    },
    "userId": "3544354",
    "email": "jacob@yahoo.com",
    "name": "Jacob Martin"
  },
  {
    "additionalAttribute": {
      "productName": "Monthly",
      "applicationName": "MSOffice",
      "lastActive": "1705088663"
    },
    "userId": "4545456",
    "email": "leo@yahoo.com",
    "name": "Leo Biz"
  }
]

Its not giving desired output. Can anyone help me with this?

You can group by the indexes of the "userList" array as well, through adding &1 symbols such as
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "totalApplication": {
        "products": {
          "*": {
            "userList": {
              "*": {
                "productUserId": "=concat(@(3,planName),'-',@(1,userId),'-',@(1,email),'-',@(1,userName),'-',@(1,lastActive))"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "totalApplication": {
        "products": {
          "*": {
            "userList": {
              "*": {
                "email|userId": "@1,productUserId.&1.&",
                "userName": "@1,productUserId.&1.name",
                "productUserId|lastActive": "@1,productUserId.&1.additionalAttribute.&",
                "@2,productName": "@1,productUserId.&1.additionalAttribute.productName",
                "@4,applicationName": "@1,productUserId.&1.additionalAttribute.applicationName"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]

